# Zend framework 2 logoutAction

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How to implement logout action in Zend Framework 2?
I am building my first ever zend application for matrimony site.
When I click on logout link user is logged out but his session is not expired,like when I click on the menu of edit profile or search profile the user session is still active.So how will I be able to implement that.

**LoginController**

```
public function indexAction()
{
$id=$this->params()->fromQuery('id');  
    if($id!="")
    {
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $sql = "UPDATE projects SET confirmation='Y' where memcode = '$id'";
        $statement = $dbAdapter->query($sql);
        $result    = $statement->execute();
    }
    $form = new LoginForm();
    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' =>$form));
    return $viewModel;
    }
    public function getAuthService()
    {

if (! $this->authservice) {
$dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$dbTableAuthAdapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter,'projects','email','password', 'MD5(?)');
$authService = new AuthenticationService();
$authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);
$this->authservice = $authService;
}
return $this->authservice;
}

public function processAction()
{
$this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()->setIdentity($this->request->getPost('email'))->setCredential($this->request->getPost('password'));
$result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();
if ($result->isValid()) {
$this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->write($this->request->getPost('email'));
return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array(
'controller' => 'login',
'action' => 'confirm'

));
}
else {
return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array(
'controller' => 'login',
'action' => 'index1'
));
}
}
public function confirmAction()
{
    $user_email = $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->read();
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $sql = "SELECT name,memcode,gender,castenobar FROM projects where email = '$user_email'";
    $statement = $dbAdapter->query($sql);
    $result    = $statement->execute();
    $user = $result->current();
    $user_session = new Container('user');
    $user_name = $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->read();
    $user_session->username=  $user['name'];
    $user_session->usermemcode=  $user['memcode'];
    $user_session->usergender=  $user['gender'];
    $user_session->usercastenobar=  $user['castenobar'];
    $username = $user_session->username;
    $usergender = $user_session->usergender;
    $usercastenobar = $user_session->usercastenobar;
    if($usercastenobar=='Y'){
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$statement = $dbAdapter->query($sql);
$result    = $statement->execute();
$selectData = array();
foreach ($result as $res) {
       $selectData[]=$res;
      }
    return new ViewModel(array(
           'selectData' => $selectData,
           'user_name' => $username
         ));

    }
    else
    {
    $sql="select * from projects where gender !='".$usergender."' and castenobar='N'";
    //echo $sql;
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$statement = $dbAdapter->query($sql);
$result    = $statement->execute();
$selectData = array();
foreach ($result as $res) {
       $selectData[]=$res;
      }
    return new ViewModel(array(
           'selectData' => $selectData,
           'user_name' => $username
         ));

    }

}
public function logoutAction()
{

//$this->getAuthService()->clearIdentity();
$storage = new \Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session();
$storage->clear();
return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array(
'controller' => 'login',
'action' => 'index'
));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "logoutAction()" should look like this:

```
public function logoutAction()
{
    $name = 'Zend_Auth' ;
    $container = new Container($name);
    $container->getManager()->getStorage()->clear($name);

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array(
               'controller' => 'login',
               'action' => 'index'
           ));
}
```

If you don't define name of session's container, use the default name 'Zend_Auth' in $name, otherwise in $name you must use your own name for the session container.

Your "$this->redirect()..." doesn't logout user and it doesn't clear the 'Zend_Auth' container. It only redirects to another site. The user is still logged in / active. To be sure that the user is logged in or logged out you can use:

```
$auth = new AuthenticationService();
if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array(
     'controller' => 'login',
     'action' => 'index'
   ));
}
```